# Cooperative Threading, No assignment

Tags: multithreading, scheme, continuations

To preface I love rolling my own, this is an exercise for learning purposes, but I want to take the information from this exercise eventually and implement some macros encapsulating the behaviors here. Thats why im using alot of `let` because nothing is finalized yet and defines are too "heavy".

So you can use call/cc to implement all kinds of different cooperative threading constructs, and the model for a thread that im using is generally:

```
(let ((generic-thread
       (lambda (cc)
         (let loop ((cc cc))
           (printf "doing stuff~N")
           (loop (call/cc cc)))))) ;this is the magic, it calls the calling continuation
  (let loop ((its 0)               ;and then loops with the result of that
             (cc generic-thread))  ;so when its resumed, it still has its new state
    (if (< its 10)
        (loop (+ its 1) (call/cc cc))))) ;just repeats the procedure for the demonstration
```

And so far this works really well actually.

So in my problem, I feel ive identified a few base cases, threads with an exit clause, those without them, and threads that cannot be resumed, or one shots (essentially just a function call, but I want to be consistent so it has to be in a "thread" and not just a function call)

```
(let ((spawn-thread
       (lambda (it . args)
         (call/cc (apply it args))))

      (main 
        (lambda (label reps . sequence)
         ;for consistency, main is also a thread, but does not need to be
         ;this will take a number of repetitions, and a sequence of continuations
         ;to call, pushing the continuation returned from the top continuation in 
         ;sequence to the end, and then calling the loop again
          (lambda (cc)
            (let loop ((sequence sequence) (state 0))
              (printf "IN MAIN THREAD STATE: ~A~N---" state)
              (if (< state reps) ;this is essentially a queue but without assignment
                  (loop `(,@(cdr sequence) ,(call/cc (car sequence))) 
                         (+ state 1)))))))

      (with-exit 
       (lambda (label data) 
       ;thread with exit case
         (lambda (cc)
           (let loop ((cc cc) (done (lambda () #f)) (state 0))
             (cond ((done) (cc data)) ;if done was replaced with something else that                                   
                                      ;could at some point return true, this is where
                                      ;the thread would exit
                   (else              
                     (printf "IN THREAD ~A TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: ~A~N" label state)
                     (loop (call/cc cc) done (+ state 1))))))))

      (no-exit 
        (lambda (label data) 
        ;no exit case, can be resumed arbitrarily
          (lambda (cc)
            (let loop ((cc cc) (state 0))
              (printf "IN THREAD ~A TYPE: NO-EXIT STATE: ~A~N" label state)
              (loop (call/cc cc) (+ state 1))))))


      (no-reps 
        (lambda (label data) 
        ;breaks it for some reason? 
        ;would be called, do its stuff and then
        ;go back to the calling continuation
         (lambda (cc)               
           (printf "IN THREAD ~A TYPE: NO-REPS~N" label)
           (call/cc cc)))))

  (spawn-thread main 'main 10
        (spawn-thread with-exit 1 '())
        (spawn-thread no-exit 2 '())
        (spawn-thread with-exit 3 '())
        ;(spawn-thread no-reps 4 '())) uncomment to see error
        ))
```

So whats up with no-reps? why does running it as one of the threads in main lead to an infinite loop?

output from example with commented line:

```
IN THREAD 1 TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: 0
IN THREAD 2 TYPE: NO-EXIT STATE: 0
IN THREAD 3 TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: 0
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 0
---IN THREAD 1 TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: 1
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 1
---IN THREAD 2 TYPE: NO-EXIT STATE: 1
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 2
---IN THREAD 3 TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: 1
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 3
---IN THREAD 1 TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: 2
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 4
---IN THREAD 2 TYPE: NO-EXIT STATE: 2
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 5
---IN THREAD 3 TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: 2
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 6
---IN THREAD 1 TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: 3
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 7
---IN THREAD 2 TYPE: NO-EXIT STATE: 3
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 8
---IN THREAD 3 TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: 3
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 9
---IN THREAD 1 TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: 4
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 10
```

Uncommented:

```
IN THREAD 1 TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: 0
IN THREAD 2 TYPE: NO-EXIT STATE: 0
IN THREAD 3 TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: 0
IN THREAD 4 TYPE: NO-REPS
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 0
---IN THREAD 1 TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: 1
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 1
---IN THREAD 2 TYPE: NO-EXIT STATE: 1
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 2
---IN THREAD 3 TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: 1
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 3
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 0
---IN THREAD 1 TYPE: WITH-EXIT STATE: 1
......... ;profit????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which implementation you are using, but I couldn't get infinite loop just uncommenting the expression. (I've used couple of R6RS implementations, including Racket.)

To make things easier, I've stripped your code like this:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))

(define (print . args) (for-each display args) (newline))

(let ((spawn-thread
       (lambda (it . args)
         (call/cc (apply it args))))
      (main
       (lambda (label reps . sequence)
         (lambda (cc)
           (print sequence)
           (let loop ((sequence sequence) (state 0))
             (print "IN MAIN THREAD STATE: " state)
             (display  "---")
             (if (< state reps)
                 (let ((next `(,@(cdr sequence) ,(call/cc (car sequence))) ))
                   (loop next (+ state 1))))))))
      (no-reps
       (lambda (label data)
         (lambda (cc)
           (print "IN THREAD "label" TYPE: NO-REPS")
           (call/cc cc)))))
  (spawn-thread main 'main 10
                ;; *1
                (spawn-thread no-reps 4 '())))
```

The point is the returning continuation of `*1`. The procedure `spawn-thread` executes the `no-reps` procedure, and `no-reps` returns the given continuation whose next process is calling `spawn-thread` of main. Thus, what `no-reps` actually does in this context is duplicating the main thread. The following execution result, run on Racket, shows it:

```
IN THREAD 4 TYPE: NO-REPS
{#<continuation>}
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 0
---{#<continuation>}
IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 0
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 1
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 1
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 2
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 2
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 3
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 3
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 4
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 4
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 5
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 5
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 6
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 6
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 7
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 7
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 8
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 8
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 9
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 9
---IN MAIN THREAD STATE: 10
---%
```